# Convert the retrieved data to object by using getValue(classname)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following structure in my database in Firebase:

[image]

Now I have the following code:

```
final String fDate = DAL_Utilities.ConvertDateToFirebaseDate(date);
URL url = new URL(DAL_Utilities.DatabaseURL + "users/" + user.getName()+ "/Stimmungsabfrage/" + fDate);
Firebase root = new Firebase(url.toString());
root.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    Object obj = dataSnapshot.getChildren();


} 
@Override
public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

}
});
```

But after executing `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` I have node  **20170316**. I have a class `StimmungAbfrage`:

```
public class StimmungAbfrage {
    public String Date;
    public Integer Angespannt ;
    public Integer Mitteilsam;
    public Integer Muede;
    public Integer Selbstsicher;
    public Integer Tatkraeftig;
    public Integer Traurig;
    public Integer Wuetend;
    public Integer Zerstreut;
    }
```

The data under the node with value **V** should be converted to an object of this class. But my current value is on **20170316**. How can I get the snapshot of **V** so that I can execute `getValue(StimmungAbfrage.classname)` on it?

Comment: It's better if you could post the database structure in text rather than a screenshot (simply export JSON file from Firebase console and copy the relevant node). That being said I saw the string starting with -KfN...,which is a pushID generated by Firebase, am I right? Will there be more children under this pushId node  other than V? If not it's better if you could save the `StimmungAbfrage` class attributes as a direct child of the generated push ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve node of data and parse it to a Java class object you can use the getValue method.

**getValue(Class valueType)**

Provided that:

1. The class has a default empty constructor.
2. The class must contain public getters for the properties to be assigned.

For example, take a look at this example class definition;

```
    public class User {

          private String display_name;
          private String email;

          public User() {
            // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(User.class)
          }

          public User(String display_name, String email) {
              this.display_name = display_name;
              this.email = email;
          }

          public String getDisplay_name() {
              return display_name;
          }

          public String getEmail() {
              return email;
          }

      }
```

So make sure your **StimmungAbfrage** class adheres to Firebase guidelines.

**UPDATE**

I have two solutions in this answer;

1. How to retrieve the data with your current database structure.
2. How to retrieve data according to a less complex database structure which I recommend.

**Solution 1**

Your current structure holds data like:

```
"20170316" : {
  "-KfNx5TBo4yQpfN07Ekh" : {
    "V":{
    "Angespannt" : 3,
    etc..
    }
  }
}
```

You would retrieve the data like this:

```
String strKey = "";
List<StimmungAbfrage> listOfObjects = new ArrayList<>();

root.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

 //retrieve key -KfNx5TBo4yQpfN07Ekh
 for (DataSnapshot datachild : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
     strKey = datachild .getKey();
 }

  //use the key to access inner children and parse them to an object and add it to list

    dbRef.child(strKey).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

          for(DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

            StimmungAbfrage stimmungAbfrage = dataSnap.getValue(StimmungAbfrage.class);
            listOfObjects.add(stimmungAbfrage);

          }
       }
   }

.....
```

**NOTE:** `dbRef` should be pointing to the same node as`root`reference was plus the push ID key, which is added afterwards like :

```
dbRef.child(strKey) // strKey hold the pushID (-KfNx5TBo4yQpfN07Ekh)
```

**Solution 2**

Using the data structure that I recommend, which would look something like this:

```
"20170316" : {
  "-KfNx5TBo4yQpfN07Ekh" : {
    "Angespannt" : 3,
    etc..
  }
}
```

Provided that there wont be any more nested children in **-KfNx5TBo4yQpfN07Ekh** node (since you didn't specify), I recommend this approach.

```
StimmungAbfrage stimmungAbfrage; //global scope

@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

  stimmungAbfrage = dataSnapshot.getValue(StimmungAbfrage.class);

}
...
```

For more info: [Read and Write Data on Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)

HTH.

Comment: Thanks @RamithDR but there are other childer under the node -KfNx5TBo4yQpfN07Ekh like "V" (as "N"). So the first solution you offered is just possible, isn't it?

Comment: @MoProg I edited solution 1 to better suit your scenario, you will have an Arraylist of `StimmungAbfrage` objects in the end.